# background-image height and width during :active on dropdown select using fancyfields jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, html-select

I'm customizing a select dropdown using the jQuery plugin [FancyFields](http://www.jqfancyfields.com/).  The select dropdown is specifically for the latest version of Google Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.63 m).

[Link to the select](http://dataglyph.com/barrettsandbox/droplist_mockup/)

One of the effects I want to achieve is having a 3 px wide border show up on :active [like this](http://postimg.org/image/pv69ysxyb/).  The border is being displayed only 1px high and 2px wide on the select currently.

The :active state I'm interested is applied to:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ffSelectButton" style="height: 28px;"><span>ABC Widgets</span></a>
```

With this css:

```
element.style {
height: 28px;
}
.ffSelect > a {
background-position: right -128px;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
outline: 0;
cursor: default;
}
```

How can I increase how much of the background-img can be displayed on :active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use another plugin if you want to achieve such output or alter the actual background images, there is no way to do what you are asking for due to the way this plugin is written.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The background image is actually different (I modified the sprite sheet based on the original one), but I think due to the nature of the jquery plugin the element height is always generated at 28px.  I will look into a new plugin.